# parse.com open-source alternatives for backend

Tags: mysql, database, cloud, parse-platform

Just wondering if there is a free `parse.com` alternative that allows one to arbitrarily store data in tables and create databases on the fly (say in mysql) that works like parse.com.

I'd love to know and use it before spending time to create one.

Thanks!

Comment: As of 02/28/2016 Parse is shutting down.

Comment: At the time, Parse anounces it will be shoot dows, we will have to find a alternative not only for the easiness, but meanly for the amonth of data that can be stored for free.

Comment: Looks like this question has to be revisited. Should we choose a different service or is there a cheap way to run your own parse server?

Comment: As Parse is shutting down, really really want updated answers to this question.

Comment: I wrote a blog post pre-Parse shutting down; with the exception of its recommendation to use Parse, it's still relevant: http://georgestocker.com/2015/04/03/mbaas-where-are-they-now/

Comment: There is a list of parse alternatives, including open source alternatives, available at https://github.com/relatedcode/ParseAlternatives

Answer (score 24):

**This answer has been updated to take into account the Parse.com shutdown. Parse Server (the parse.com service) is now available open source.**

Go with Parse Server, running on Heroku and mLab - seriously.

There are 4 compelling reasons to do this:

1. It's really well developed. There are APIs for a dozen platforms, including mobile and web. The time you would spend just rebuilding the security and extensibility is huge.
2. Parse is free* (mLab and Heroku cost at scale). You can build a huge user base before it costs anything. I currently have apps with 50k+ active users for which I pay zero. (See my answer here for this in more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26809697/parse-request-per-second-too-expensive-want-to-get-personal-aws-developed-advi/26846950#26846950)
3. The documentation and community is excellent. I have found answers to every question on their systems either neatly laid out in their docs (which include an awesome guide as well as standard class documentation) or via Stack Overflow. It is hard to quantify how much faster and more fun this makes development.
4. Even with Parse.com shutting down, there is a huge community that will keep the technology moving. It's a simple, fantastic API and server structure.

Comment: Couldn't agree more!

Comment: I would be worried about the "1000 records" limits to queries (and even sub-queries used in joins). If you have a lot of data, parse can quickly become a problem...

Comment: @RamanpreetSingh - The solution is paging.  If you watch the Parse videos on this topic their reasoning behind 1000 row per PAGE of a query makes sense and will likely lead to a better user experience.

Comment: The reasons one would not use Parse.com are nothing to do with the reasons cited above. The biggest reasons for me have in the past been 1) the lack of a way to run the backend with suitable unit and integration tests   2) The strategic question of 'do I trust Facebook with my customer data'. 3) Are there specific technical requirements on a project that Parse does not support, in future this may emerge even if Parse does everything I need right now.  Parse now offers the option of using Node.js with integration with their backend it should be possible to negate the concern over 1. 2&3 remain.

Comment: @RamanpreetSingh it's been said but pagination to the rescue!!! 1000 records is totally fine for a limit, you wouldn't want to have to have your app parse more than a 1000 at a time anyways!

Comment: Parse is going down...

Comment: This post just became irrelevant with parse going down...

Comment: On the contrary, this is now hugely relevant (again).

Comment: Couldn't **disagree** more.

Comment: Parse.com has now open sourced the parse server and is compatible with the same client SDKs

Comment: Great answer, Ryan! You can't go wrong with Heroku and MongoLab: http://blog.parse.com/announcements/hosting-your-own-parse-on-aws-and-heroku/

Comment: The server running on Heroku's basic free plan must sleep 6 hours a day (it sleeps if there is no traffic for 30min)! How do you deal with that in your apps with 50k users? are you upgrading to hobby plan and pay or...?

Comment: What is your dynos setup on Heroku?

Answer (score 7):

As this was recently active I'll add my 2€

I've looked around for a few months and the best one I have found so far is Loopback which is a MEAN based service and its open sourced. It seems to have a few heavyweight users including some who explicitly say they have used it as a migration route from Parse.com

http://loopback.io/

Technically it has a lot of similarities to the Parse stack with support for User accounts etc. Its opensource and I have so far brought it up on AWS for which the creators provide a preconfigured AMI

This does not have exactly all the same parts as Parse, but the core ones are there and you can roll whatever you like.

I intend building a front end to Parse using this and express to fill areas that Parse doesn't do and to provide a means of migrating from Parse that retains broadly the same technical/architectural tools. The associated Strongloop tools/service appears to provide a nice ops package once one leaves the managed service provided by Parse.

One big advantage is that you are not restricted to any particular database and if the app would work better with MySQL you can use that or something else instead of Mongo.

I have yet to find anyone else who has used it to compare notes.

Edit :

Loopback (or the company) has now been acquired by IBM, from my perspective this means it better competes with Parse on a strategic level as it has a major backer for the technology. I'm still using Parse on my own (and customers) projects but looking to try Loopback on a future personal project.

Comment: With Parse.com shutting down I'm looking at AWS Mobile Hub and Microsoft Azure Mobile App services as competing options for Parse. Neither of those should go away. Now I'm more worried about the IBM takeover of Loopback than I was before.

Comment: OK, creative procrastination has worked out quite well as I'm now using ParseServer open source with a service provider Back4App.com which so far is looking at a very low friction way of migrating a Parse.com app.  There are many options now and it does rather look that ParseServer in its open source form carries with it the excellent ease of use that Parse.com offered.   Now I'm thinking I might use ParseServer more in future, though Google's offerings with Firebase also look tempting.

Answer (score 2):

You can try out [apiOmat](http://apiomat.com). It's a BaaS (Backend as a Service) hosted in Germany and protected bei german law without any NSA or prism stuff. You can work with generated SDKs so it will be very easy to store data.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not open source

Comment: Do you work for the BND?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at:
http://helios.io and
http://deployd.com.

They look OK.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a list of Cloud based backends and front-end helpers. I am not sure whether you are specifically looking for mobile?

Most of these are for mobile specifically, but can also be used for any service. I only used Appery/Parse.com for now, but KnackHQ also seems really promising! If you want more you should try to google for [BAAS (backend as a service)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backend_as_a_service) providers. Some are free and/or cheap! Hope it helps you.

1. [Appery](http://appery.io/)
2. [Stackmob](https://www.stackmob.com/)
3. [Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/)
4. [Cloudmine](https://cloudmine.me/)
5. [Icenium](http://www.icenium.com/features)
6. [KnackHQ](https://www.knackhq.com/)

Comment: None of these is open-source