# MySQL Cloud DB API's

Tags: mysql, api, parse-platform, openstack, rackspace-cloud

I'm looking to use an online database that various apps (iOS, Android, etc), a website & some hardware products will communicate with & manipulate as part of a new web / app / IoT product-service.

I am technically competent, but am not an app dev.  I have a Cloud Server with Rackspace & have tinkered with their Cloud DB's.  I come from a web design background & am competent at setting up a MySQL Server & administering the databases.

Therefore, I have decided that for prototyping purposes - MySQL is probably the way to go.  I understand that I need an API, which will act as a middle man between the various apps, website, etc.

Rackspace runs Openstack, which I understand supports REST API - which has a library of useful code to build an API in say Python.

I understand that Rackspace provide coding services to build the API & I have asked them for a quotation.

I'm also looking at Parse & Firebase as a prototyping alternative.  These will presumably allow the app to be built without needing an API (nor a separate DB for that matter).

This will save cost initially as the API won't need to be developed as part of producing a working prototype.

So, my question...

What sort of time would you suggest is required to build an API querying a single database with say 50 different columns over several tables?  Would it typically be say a weeks worth of work for a competent developer or realistically a lot more (making Parse or Firebase the sensible option).

Also, is there another option that I should be looking at?

Comment: `select * from table` -> `var_dump($result_array)` is about 15 seconds' work and would constitute an "api".

Comment: between 4 and 6 weeks at least

Comment: Your question is not really possible to answer, you already got answers that tell you between 15 seconds and 6 weeks - it's absolutely prone to opinion. Any app that's capable of performing an HTTP request towards an endpoint constitutes that you have a REST API. Whether your API exposes entirety of MySQL's functionality or just a subset of it brings up the question of what that db is supposed to save and what your API is supposed to do - as you can imagine, you can come up with billion of useful scenarios. TL;DR: not possible to answer. Also, offtopic since there is no programming problem.

Comment: Why does it take you eight paragraphs to get to your actual question? We don't need all that detail.

Comment: I get really annoyed when people like the above that come up with elitist "It isn't a question without //, @, #, or ; in it".  The point of Stack Overflow is "A language-independent collaboratively edited question and answer site for programmers."  I'm on the forum to learn about a programming project, like I'd go to a networking event to discuss a problem with knowledgeable people.  I give an overview so to give a rough indication of the scale & setting.  I'm just looking for some indication (which I now have) - I.E: several weeks plus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should consider Parse.com, not just for prototyping but as a full solution.

**I have been using Parse for 3 years now, with great success. There are several compelling reasons, [which I outline here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021314/parse-com-open-source-alternatives-for-backend/30243548#30243548).**

The bottom line: don't pay someone to re-invent the wheel when it comes to a REST api, security and scalability. Getting those things built in is the reason companies like Parse exist. I've run projects from the very small (a few hundred users) to the very large (hundreds of thousands) on the platform with no problems and a much faster time-to-market.

Comment: OK, thanks for this. If its say a 1 week task to get an API formed - that can then be built upon, then its a none event, otherwise Parse will be the route for Prototyping.  Its no good for me for scaling though due to the reliance on a third party for one of the key assets.