# Parse VS Amazon WB VS Google Platform

Tags: amazon-web-services, parse-platform, google-cloud-platform

I have been trying to develop some apps and recently came across a question. What server should I use: Parse, Amazon, Google?
When i first learned how to create user-related apps i was taught with Parse. But after reading many things i noticed that many of the big apps go with Amazon and Google servers.
What is the major difference? For example with Parse i get specific functions for signing a user and lots of other useful ones but i can't find similar ones for Google/Amazon. Has anyone come across this issue in the early programming days? How and where can i learn to do what i do with Parse using Amazon/Google?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse is your best choice for short time-to-market, built-in functionality, and ease of use.

You can check out my complete answer to this question here: [parse.com open-source alternatives for backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021314/parse-com-open-source-alternatives-for-backend/30243548#30243548)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have read your answer to the other post and I am now convinced on keeping on with Parse. I have realized that it becomes extremely hard to implement so many functions in AWS, mainly when it's you and your friend, newly formed iOS developers.

Comment: Glad to hear it! (Also, I'm guessing by your rating that you are new here; it is usually customary to mark and an answer correct / up vote it if it answers your question. Thanks!)

Comment: Unfortunately, parse is going to be down: http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/

Comment: try back4app :) if its going down